# PHP 8.0.2 - Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug'

Tags: php, xdebug

Pasted my php_info() on the Xdebug installation wizard and followed all the steps.

[image: Screenshot of recommended steps from Xdebug Windows Installation wizard]

However, I keep getting

> PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: ext\xdebug (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_xdebug.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Using Windows 11, PHP 8.0.2 CLI

**UPDATE:**
Tried running `php -i` via CMD and I get the following popup. I don't know if it's related to the issue:

[image: CMD output popup]

Comment: Is the file called `php_xdebug.dll` is in your ext directory of the PHP version that `you are running` ?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it to `php_xdebug.dll` and saved in my `ext` folder

Comment: What is your `extensions_dir` php.ini setting set to?

Comment: `extension_dir = "ext"`

Comment: Please see the update on the post. Unable to get php info on the terminal using cmd. Idk if this is related

Comment: @Ndiritu There seems to be an issue with the PHP 8.0.2 Windows build. Please upgrade your PHP to a newer version (at least 8.0.7 or newer).

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for letting me know. I ended up changing versions and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to choose the right dll version - TS or NTS, 32 or 64 bit from:

```
PHP 8.0 VS16 (64 bit)
PHP 8.0 VS16 (32 bit)
PHP 8.0 VS16 TS (64 bit)
PHP 8.0 VS16 TS (32 bit)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the php version is ts or nts to make sure you install xdebug in the same version

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but your answer doesn't add any new information. Please read existing answers before adding your own.